# What is the correct preposition between these? "I am all ears TO? what you want to say

Tags: grammar

I hope it is not a phrase that can only be used without preposition because I can not see any sense in such a case. why we cannot? to sounds to me correct does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Be all ears' is an idiom. It means to be very keen, interested, ready to hear what someone says or is going to say. For example:

Tell me what you want to say - I am all ears.

You can replace 'be all ears' with 'be listening' that's more common in use.

Tell me what you want to say - I am listening.

But the idiom is more emphatic than 'be listening'.

You don't use the preposition to after all ears.  However, you can use 'to' after the verb listening.

Tell me what you want to say - I am listening to you.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+am+all+ears%2C+I+am+listening&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20am%20all%20ears%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20am%20listening%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 3):

> I have some exciting news!
>   -- I'm all ears.

We don't normally say "I'm all ears {to what you have to say}".

We say only "I'm all ears."

The meaning = OK, let me hear it.  Tell me.  I'm listening.

The literal meaning:  I am a creature who is made of ears. No other body parts.

We also say "I'm all thumbs". The literal meaning is, "I don't have any fingers, only ten thumbs."  And it means "My hands are clumsy, not deft."